# Xaringan does render a chunk with chunk option class.source defined. How to solve it?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, xaringan

I am using `xaringan` to create slides with stan code. I want to present the model code and save it using the syntax below. However, when I add the `class.source = "stan"` (to highlight the stan syntax appropriately) option the code does not render as it should:

````r
---
output:   xaringan::moon_reader
---

---

```{cat, engine.opts = list(file = 'code/stan/ex1.stan'), name = "ex1.stan", class.source = "stan"}
data {
    int<lower=0> N; //number of data
    vector[N] x; //covariates
    vector[N] y; //variates
}

parameters {
  real alpha; //intercept
  real beta; //slope
  real<lower=0> sigma; //scatter
}

model {
  //priors
  alpha ~ normal(0, 10);
  beta ~ normal(0, 10);
  sigma ~ normal(0, 1);
  
  y ~normal(alpha + beta * x, sigma); //likelihood
}
````

[image]

So the desired result would be:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to see only syntax highlighting? Or you need to display an output of model too?

Comment: Only syntax highlighting. The model output, is in another chunk with the corresponding R syntax.

Comment: With these borders (red and grey lines)?

Comment: No, the borders I have it already sorted.

Comment: Then use simply ``` ```stan your text ``` ```

Comment: No... I want the file to be generated and the source code to be highlighted. Notice the chunk options: `{cat, engine.opts = list(file = 'code/stan/ex1.stan'), name = "ex1.stan", class.source = "stan"}`

Comment: Hm. You want this: "When I switch to slide with stan code - I should to see a highlighed code in slide and ```xxx.stan``` file in the the slides' folder"?

Comment: Yes! Exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you in comments above, you simply need this:

````
---
output:   xaringan::moon_reader
---

---
```{cat, engine.opts = list(file = "test.stan", lang = "stan")}
data {
    int<lower=0> N; //number of data
    vector[N] x; //covariates
    vector[N] y; //variates
}

parameters {
  real alpha; //intercept
  real beta; //slope
  real<lower=0> sigma; //scatter
}

model {
  //priors
  alpha ~ normal(0, 10);
  beta ~ normal(0, 10);
  sigma ~ normal(0, 1);
  
  y ~normal(alpha + beta * x, sigma); //likelihood
}
```
````

Comment: Yes, simply perfect... https://i.imgur.com/GFcR4bH.png

Comment: @Sinval Yes, looks cool. I like your elegant style of the code block.

Comment: thank you. As you can see, it works with many different languages: https://i.imgur.com/nfZc46Z.png

Comment: @Sinval Is your solution based on  ```fieldset``` element?

Comment: No, CSS and JS. See more here: https://github.com/gadenbuie/xaringanExtra/issues/147

Comment: @Sinval Thank you very much! Sometimes I thought to do something similar, but always haven't got down to that problem :-)

Comment: Great, if you need some reproducible examples, tell me. I have the files ready. :) Cheers!